# VM player win7 setting up proxy for ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, vmware

I am using VM Player the latest one, and using the win7 x64 as the host OS and installed ubuntu as the guest OS on the VMplayer,
but the problem is that in win7 is already using proxy and able to acess internet but not sure what settings to use to be able to access the internet in ubuntu i know the proxy name and the username and the password but not sure where to put this information any clear guide please.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to set up a Ubuntu desktop (GUI) to use a proxy server:

> [How to Configure Ubuntu Desktop to use your proxy server](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-configure-ubuntu-desktop-to-use-your-proxy-server.html)

If you are looking to set proxy settings on a Ubuntu Server edition VM, you can enable it in a couple places for customized functionality:

**Just Aptitude**

```
gksudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf:
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
```

**BASH rc method**

This method adds a two lines to your .bashrc file in your $HOME directory. This method is useful if you would like apt-get and other applications for instance wget, to use a http-proxy.

```
gksudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

Add these lines to the bottom of your ~/.bashrc file (substitute your details for yourproxyaddress and proxyport)

```
http_proxy=http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport
export http_proxy
```

Save the file. Close your terminal window and then open another terminal window or source the ~/.bashrc file:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Test your proxy with sudo apt-get update and whatever networking tool you desire. You can use firestarter or conky to see active connections.

If you make a mistake and go back to edit the file again, you can close the terminal and reopen it or you can source ~/.bashrc as shown above.